# Monitoring Windows Memory Mapped Files

Tags: windows, memory-management, memory-mapped-files

In Windows, how can I keep track of the file mapping objects created by CreateFileMapping()? Basically I want to know how many memory mapped files are in use and the 
information like their names, sizes, etc.  Thanks!

Comment: I am also looking for a programmatic way to discover which processes have a memory-mapped file open, or a utility like handle.exe that can provide that information in a parseable format.  Process Explorer cannot be effectively used on a headless machine or when the issue is transient.

Answer (score 10):

SysInternals Process Explorer will what memory mapped files each running process has open:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx

Comment: Thanks for letting me know this great tool. I would also like to know how I can do in my own program. Any clues?

Comment: Please, can you tell me where is it exactly ?

Comment: Ehsan - they show up when you enable the lower pane and switch to Handles mode (View, Lower Pane View, Handles). When you click on a process in the upper pane the mapped files will show up as Section entries.

Comment: Is there a tool for dumping *all* file mappings? My problem is that after a crash the mappings are not removed even if all the processes that had them mapped have exited (either gracefully or ungracefully).

I presume it's the references from those crashed processes (that were not removed properly) keeping them areound. I know restarting the machine will make them go away, but that's a clumsy workaround, not a solution, to get rid of those orphaned mappings.