# Get a list of all registered MemoryMapFiles in c#?

Tags: c#, .net, memory-mapped-files

Is there an method in c# that lists all the opened or created MemoryMapFiles in c# ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Monitoring Windows Memory Mapped Files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1563943/monitoring-windows-memory-mapped-files)

Comment: 1st possible is far from exact, 2nt that question has no answers yet.

Comment: all open memory files on your app, on your computer??

Comment: actually both are needed in my case.

Answer (score -1):

It depends on what you mean when you say "in c#". Using managed code? No. Using native code? Yes. You can use `VirtualQueryEx` to get all the memory allocations for a process, and it will tell if you if a allocation is a memory mapped file in the `MEMORY_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure `Type` member.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366907(v=vs.85).aspx

If you want to see how to use it in C#, check out

https://github.com/google/sandbox-attacksurface-analysis-tools/tree/e8f5bb1c1a60d744f7b0cb17e028969df01e51e7/NtApiDotNet